# JPA join on legacy database non-primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following tables in a legacy database:

```
Table1 
+ Table1ID PK
+ Table1Code

Table2
+ Table2ID PK
+ Table1Code
```

The convention is that there is only 1 Table1Code for each Table1ID. Table2 has a one to many relationship with Table1.

I want to reference them both as JPA objects. Is this possible using `@OneToMany` and specifying the `@JoinColumn`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just have to use the `referencedColumnName` attribute of the `JoinColumn` annotation:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "Table1Code", referencedColumnName = "Table1Code")
private List<Table2> table2s;
```